# How to stop specific schedule task (cron job) in laravel 5 on live server cpanel

Tags: scheduled-tasks, schedule, job-scheduling, cron-task, laravel-jobs

I have created multiple schedule tasks in laravel 5, and created cron job on cpanel it is working fine. But now i want to stop specific schedule task, i have comment the command and remove class from app/Console/kernel.php file, but still it is running on live server on that specific time.

**Befor in kernel.php**

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\CreatePostingSchedules::class,
    Commands\ChangeCreatedPostDuration::class,
    Commands\abc::class,
    Commands\xyz::class,
    Commands\NewMonthUser::class,
    Commands\DeliverOrdersWithCourier::class,
];
```

Now Remove the class **Commands\ChangeCreatedPostDuration::class**

**After Removed the class:**

```
protected $commands = [
Commands\CreatePostingSchedules::class,
Commands\abc::class,
Commands\xyz::class,
Commands\NewMonthUser::class,
Commands\DeliverOrdersWithCourier::class,
];
```

But still it is running on live server.

Please anyone can help ? how to stop this specific schedule task ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have completely removed the scheduled function/command from "Kernel.php" of your Laravel 5 and that you do not have related manual CronJob in your cPanel -> CronJobs.
You might also want to check this article: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-stop-scheduled-tasks-from-running-in-kernelphp